# Bhattacharyya Coefficient vs. The overlap of two discrete probability distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am interested in measuring the overlap of two discrete probability distributions with given density functions $f$ and $g$ respectively.

It seems to me that this is equal to
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \sum_{x\in \Omega} \min(f(x),g(x)).
\end{equation}

However, when googling this problem, it seems that the standard measure for overlap is the Bhattacharyya Coefficient (BC), which is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \sum_{x\in \Omega} \sqrt{f(x)*g(x)}.
\end{equation}

I understand that BC is an approximation (?), but why approximate something that is readily computable?

In particular, in the Monte Carlo estimation based on a set of $n$ samples $X_i$ drawn uniformly over $\Omega$, is there any reason to prefer 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{f(X_i)*g(X_i)}.
\end{equation}
over
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \min(f(X_i),g(X_i)).
\end{equation}
?

Comment: What makes you think one is an approximation of the other?

Comment: To me "overlap" between two distributions is a well-defined quantity (shown in [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6eFin.png)). Since BC does not compute this quantity exactly, I assumed it to be an approximation thereof. Also, Wikipedia states: "The Bhattacharyya coefficient is an approximate measurement of the amount of overlap between two statistical samples."([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance#Bhattacharyya_coefficient))

Comment: I think "approximate" there means that the Bhattacharyya coefficient is an approximation for the Bhattacharyya distance between the two unknown population distributions. It does not mean it is an approximation for the overlap as you define it. Although Bhattacharyya distance does not satisfy the triangle inequality, there is a transformation of it that does. Maybe that is a reason why it is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a slight misunderstanding.  The Bhattacharyya distance is a 'measure' of the overlap.  Not a 'measurement' of it.  I mean that in plain english terms.  It gives you a way of quantifying overlap, but it's not telling you the exact amount of area that overlaps.  At least that's my reading of the various references.

I believe the John L is correct in his intepretation of what 'approximate' means in context.

Comment: opinions such as "I think..." must first be conveyed as comments intead of answers if It does not Completely answer the question

Comment: would love to.  wouldn't let me comment. :D

Comment: ,Seems fair enough, Please strive to be sure about your answers, Comment such Ideas Once you get the ability